# Can selenium block the navigation request just like 'page.navigationLocked' in phantomjs?

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

When I'm using phantomjs, I can block a navigation request by setting page.navigationLocked=true.
Then all navigation request will be blocked. So I can click any anchor without navigating to another page.

Can I do the same thing in selenium? Is there any api in selenium that allow me to lock the navigation?

Comment: Not sure about that one, but you could register an event that would intercept and bury all navigation like attempts.  That isn't ideal though for what you are trying to do...

Comment: **C#** - http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html#
**Java** - http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html
**python** - https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.event_firing_webdriver.html

Comment: Another thought is that you register an event that after every step you check the page to make sure it's the same page.  If not then you can execute a `driver.Navigate().Back();`